# How to use curl to access a webpage behind a login form?

Tags: curl, http, session, web, cookie

There is this webpage I'm trying to scrape but it is behind a login form that needs user/password.
I used Firefox debug mode to find HTTP requests. Upon entering the credentials, there is a POST request which return a `set-cookie` in Response Headers. There is subsequent `GET` that uses this cookie (instead of user/pass) to finally access the actual page. The cookie has an expiration date.

I assume I have to 1- get that cookie via curl POST dumping it in a `cookie.txt`, 2- then again use curl GET with `-b cookie.txt` option (**without** needing to pass along user/pass).

I want to fetch that `set-cookie` via `curl` in command line (step 1).
I tried to replicate what Firefox did with `Copy as cURL` command on POST. It forms the curl request (with user/pass inside a `--data-raw` switch and a short `ASP.NET_SessionId` inside a `-H 'Cookie: ...`.
Problem is, it does return a header but cookie is not there. The downloaded website (HTML) indicated something went wrong.
Now, in forming up the `--data-raw`, there are fields like `__VIEWSTATE`, `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR` and `__EVENTVALIDATION` which seem to change on each `GET` of the login page. I filled them up via a little scrpting. It didn't fix the issue.

I'm using the copied curl command from firefox alongside `-c cookie.txt -D - -v` ...It does not print the cookie in headers or dump the cookie in the file.

Comment: this looks similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/45755598/1119949

Comment: @imbuedHope I've seen that post. That answer is pretty much what I'm doing (which doesn't work). Also, for this website, I used `--data-raw` to include my user/pass and didn't explicitly use `--form`s.